# CSS3 Infinite Rotation animation on iOS5

Tags: ios, animation, css, safari, mobile-safari

So I'm trying to infinitely rotate a png on my webapp for iOS but having a hard time getting it to work in the simulator. Here my CSS:

```
 #spinner { -webkit-animation: spinner 1s infinite linear; }

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,360deg); }
}
```

it works perfectly on latest Chrome.. however, mobile safari doesn't seem to like 0-360. I tried 0 to 180 and that works for some strange reason... how can i go all 360 degrees?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to put 180deg at 50% and 90deg at 25% to avoid ambiguities?

Comment: I'm going to guess that Safari treats 0 and 360deg as the same rotation position (since they are) and calculates that no transition is necessary. Change the 360deg to 359 and that should fix it

Answer (score 5):

as YuriAlbuquerque said, you can do it like this

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg); }
    25% { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,90deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,180deg); }
    75% { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,270deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,360deg); }
}
```

Removing 25% and 75% in keyframes also works but only in less than ios6. In ios6, if you don't add 25% and 75%, than it will rotate clockwise 180deg and than anticlockwise from 180deg to 360deg.

Comment: Nice trick! Now it works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari for me. :)